# Library that implements importDocument false when reading a WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl

I need to parse a wsdl file but the import files may not be available. Does anyone know of a java wsdl reader that actually implements the feature importDocuments?

API can be found here:
http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/apis/wsdl4j/javax/wsdl/xml/WSDLReader.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29.

So I need: reader.setFeature("javax.wsdl.importDocuments", false).

I have tried easyWSDL and WSDL4J and both of those try to import the documents regardless of whether the import documents are set to true of false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the java Sax Parser will let you ignore imports.

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but maybe you can parse it to a new xml file without the imports and then feed that to a wsdl parser.